# How to inject a java value in XSLT Saxon template?

Tags: saxon

I'm using `Saxon-HE` (free home edition) to parse `XML` files with `XSLT`. Now I want to inject a static value (the timestamp of the application start) into the xslt template. So that each run of the template uses the same timestamp.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static parameter

```
<xsl:param name="appStartTime" as="xs:dateTime" 
           static="yes" select="current-dateTime()"/>
```

You can supply a value for the parameter using `xsltCompiler.setParameter(QName, XdmValue)`, or it will default to the date/time at which the stylesheet was compiled.

You can reference the parameter in the body of a template in the same way as any other variable reference, using `$appStartTime`.

For a no-namespace parameter name the `QName` can be supplied as, for example `new QName("appStartTime")`.

The `XdmValue` in your case will be an `XdmAtomicValue` containing a date. Starting from a Java `LocalDate`, in Saxon 9.9, the best way to construct this is probably to use `new net.sf.saxon.DateValue(year, month, day)` extracting the fields from the `LocalDate`, then to supply this `DateValue` to `XdmAtomicValue.makeAtomicValue(Object)`.

Comment: Could you give an example for `.setParameter(QName name, XdmValue value)`? I mean, how do I have to construct Qname and XdmValue? What I actually like to pass in would be (pseudocode): `.setParameter("appStartTime", LocalDateTime.now());`.

Comment: It would be something like `.setParameter(new QName("appStartTime"), DateTimeValue.now())`. Or there's various other ways of getting a `DateTimeValue`, e.g. `DateTimeValue.fromLocalDateTime()`. Saxon 9.9 was updated to work with the new Java 8 date/time classes.

Comment: Yeah I know about the datetime creation. Problem is that the method forces the use of `XdmValue` classtype, and I don't know how I could get any java datetime into it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out a step. Will add to the answer.